# confused about law of exponent (contradiction)

Tags: exponential-function

Is the following statement true?
$$
(-1.2)^{1.6} = \sqrt[10]{(-1.2)^{16}}.
$$

Is it because $a^{0.5} = a^{1/2} = \sqrt{a}$?

Comment: It seems so...What's the problem?

Comment: well because the first gives an unreal number...

Comment: now I'm confused! Can you show me why it is an "unreal"(I think you mean imaginary) number?

Comment: non integer exponents on negative numbers are sometimes considered undefined.

Comment: so are they both equal?

Comment: Yes, either both underfined or both defined one way or another but the same for both.

Comment: The reason why your calculator gives an error is that unless #1 Your calculator does lambda calculus. #2 You give him the exponent in the form $\frac{n}{d}$, it'll use the definition $a^b = e^{b\times ln(a)}$ and since $ln(a)$ for $a < 0$ is not defined, the exponent won't be defined so the whole thing won't be defined either.

Comment: @xavierm02: I don't know if a calculator "does" lambda calculus. It might actually just be designed to know how to deal with a negative base. Or it might try to first convert the number given into a fraction.

Comment: @Thomas Well dealing with the negative case **is** converting it to a fraction...

Comment: @Thomas And if a calculator does lamba calculus, when you enter $x/x$ it answers $1$ and a calculator that does is tell you the variable isn't defined. Unless you already assigned a value to $x$ in which case you must have played with it enough to know if it has functions like $factor$ or things like that in it.

Comment: @xavierm02: I don't understand you...

Comment: @Thomas Are you a native speaker or not? Because I am not. And here's how I understood your first comment: <I don't know if a calculator "does" lambda calculus.> = <I know no way to determine whether a calculator does lambda calculus or not> | <Or it might try to first convert the number given into a fraction.> = <It might try the second definition before the first>. Is that what you actually meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take $\sqrt{}$ as example because for odd numbers, you get a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ into itself (with positive number mapped to positive numbers and negative numbers mapped to negative numbers) so the problem only arises with even numbers and once you understand for $\sqrt{}$, you'll understand for $\sqrt[4]{}$, $\sqrt[6]{}$ etc. as well.

You problem is that you didn't understand the function $\sqrt{} : \mathbb{R_+} \to  \mathbb{R_+}$ is just a convention.

When we write $\sqrt{4}$, we mean $2$ because we **chose** the **positive** real number as result for the function $\sqrt{}$ because if we didn't specify that, we wouldn't get a function since a function is something that has a unique value for each "input".

But if you try to extend that function to $\mathbb{R}$ we get $\sqrt{} : \mathbb{R} \to ?$ where does it go? Because now, for $\sqrt{-1}$, you have to decide between $i$ and $-i$...

You would pick $i$ because it looks positive but it is not... There has been a question about a way to differentiate $i$ from $-i$ recently on SO and the answers were, more or less, that you can't.

Of course, for $\mathbb{R}$, you could decide to always take the one that is a positive real number multiplied by $i$. But then you get $\sqrt{} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and you only use $i$ in $\mathbb{C}$ so you don't get a bijection.

And then if you try to extend it to $\mathbb{C}$ with $\sqrt{} : \mathbb{C} \to ?$ you can't decide which one to take unless you define some kind of sign over $\mathbb{C}$ to partition it. Which you usually don't want to do.

Plus when you work in $\mathbb{C}$, you usually just want one of the answers, of $a^2=b$ and you don't care which one you get.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents).

The problem here is that the base number $-1.2$ is negative. Some people think of negative numbers being raised to non-integer powers as being undefined. However, one might reasonably think of for example $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ as the cube root of $-1$, which is $-1$. It might be a bit confusing, but I think if you look at the Wikipedia article that I linked to above, you might find a good answer.

You have a rational exponent $1.6 = \frac{16}{10} = \frac{8}{5}$ (reduced fraction). $5$ is odd you have something well-defined and you get

$$
(-1.2)^{\frac{8}{5}} = \sqrt[5]{(-1.2)^8}.
$$

This is equal to what you have written.

Now, you might have a calculator that doesn't evaluate the left hand side. I just tried with my calculator (TI-84) and had no problem.

Comment: because when I enter the first in the calculator, it gives me an error

Comment: @user1561559: I edited

Comment: Also, relying on $(-1)^{\frac13} = -1$ can lead the unwary to conclude $-1 =  (-1)^{\frac13} = (-1)^{\frac26}=((-1)^2)^{\frac16}=1^{\frac16}=1$. Be careful with this stuff!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Indeed! Of course in your example $\frac{2}{6}$ is not reduced.